# gvim: passing the visually-selected text to the command line

Tags: command-line, vim

I use gvim to store recipes of commands that I will execute, depending on output. Currently, I select the text in gvim and paste the commands into a terminal console, but I bet there's a way I can pass the visually selected range into a command-line for execution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Assuming you mean the Vim command line:

(if you mean the OS command line, see below).

For parts of lines (i.e. no end of line character), you could do something like this:

```
" Visually select lines, then:
y:<C-R>"<ENTER>
```

where `<C-R>` means press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.  The `y` 'yanks' the selected text, the `:` enters command mode, `<C-R>"` pulls the contents of the `"` (last yanked text) register onto the command line and `<ENTER>` (obviously) runs the command.

---

If you want to do line-wise stuff, it's a bit more complicated (as the command line doesn't like `^M`s in the command).  I'd recommend something like this in your vimrc:

```
function! RunCommands()
    exe getline('.')
endfunction
command -range RunCommands <line1>,<line2>call RunCommands()
vmap ,r :RunCommands<CR>
```

Select the lines (after restarting vim) and press `,r`.

---

Another way that you may find useful is to copy the lines you want, hit `q:` to open the command line window and paste the lines you want into there and then move the cursor over the line you want and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  This has the advantage that you can edit the command before pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  It'll only run one command at a time.

### If you mean an (e.g.) Windows or Linux command line:

Use the function I listed above, but instead of:

```
exe getline('.')
```

use

```
call system(getline('.'))
```

or, if you want to see the result:

```
echo system(getline('.'))
```

or

```
echomsg system(getline('.'))
```

### For more information:

```
:help :echo
:help :echomsg
:help :messages

:help :vmap
:help :command-range
:help :command
:help :function

:help c_CTRL-R
:help :exe
:help getline()
:help system()
```

Comment: In this case, I guess `into a terminal console` means !(Vim Command line). But +1 for nice answer dealing with both cases.

Comment: You are THE BOMB! This is exactly what I was looking for, comprehensively so, too. I'll be using the echomsg line, so I can see output from the selected command. I've confirmed this tip on Mac, FWIW, but expect no issues on other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the vim GUI, you can do `set guioptions+=a`. This way, any highlighted text inside gvim in visual mode gets pasted to a clipboard.