# how to run the line of a vim script file in the buffer

Tags: vim

say i am editing my vimrc file, and i input a line like:

```
let xxx = 1
```

then i want to test this line, i have to enter the normal mode, press ':' and copy this line to the command mini-buffer...

Can i config the vim to run the line by just 1-2 key strokes?
or maybe one step further, can i run highlighted (visual mode) code area by 1-2 key strokes?
i think some one should've already done such thing but just could not find it by google or here.

thanks!

Comment: Think this is mostly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725435/gvim-passing-the-visually-selected-text-to-the-command-line

Comment: have a look at zzappers excellent guide to vim tips. Your question is answered there http://rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html

Answer (score 0):

```
":[range]Execute        Execute text lines as ex commands.
"               Handles |line-continuation|.
" The same can be achieved via "zyy@z (or yy@" through the unnamed register);
" but there, the ex command must be preceded by a colon (i.e. :ex)
command! -bar -range Execute silent <line1>,<line2>yank z | let @z = substitute(@z, '\n\s*\\', '', 'g') | @z

" [count]<Leader>e  Execute current [count] line(s) as ex commands, then
" {Visual}<Leader>e jump to the following line (to allow speedy sequential
"           execution of multiple lines).
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>e :Execute<Bar>execute 'normal! ' . v:count1 . 'j'<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <Leader>e :Execute<Bar>execute 'normal! ' . v:count1 . 'j'<CR>
```